# R - How to plot forest plot using metafor package?

Tags: r, plot, model, summary, metafor

I would like to plot a forest plot using objects saved from stat summary of models using the metafor package. in my object, there will be 5 columns: Group, sub groups, estimate, upper limit and lower limit CI, which looks like the following:

```
Group Subgroup  est   lCI hCI
A         1     0.2    ~   ~
A         2     0.3    ~   ~
A         3     0.8    ~   ~
B         1      ~     ~   ~
B         2      ~     ~   ~
B         3      ~     ~   ~
```

How can I plot a forest post that group the subgroups together and categorise as such? With the CI as error bars.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have only used the `forestplot` package before, you need to pivot it wide first, and plot it like something below:

```
library(forestplot)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

results = data.frame(Group=rep(c("A","B"),each=3),
Subgroup = rep(1:3,2),est = runif(6,min=-2,max=2))

results$lCI = results$est - 0.1
results$hCI = results$est + 0.1

df_wide = pivot_wider(results,id_cols=Group,names_from=Subgroup,values_from=c("est","lCI","hCI"))

forestplot(list(Var=df_wide[["Group"]]), 
           legend = 1:3,
           fn.ci_norm = c(fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawCircleCI),
           mean = select(df_wide,contains("est")),
           lower = select(df_wide,contains("lCI")),
           upper = select(df_wide,contains("hCI")),
           col=fpColors(box=c("blue", "darkred"))
            )
```

[image]